# Why doesn’t [Int] conform to Hashable in Swift 4.1?

Tags: swift

With Swift 4.1 (Xcode 9.3) I’m trying to create a Set of [Int], but I get:

> Type '[Int]' does not conform to the protocol 'Hashable'

But as far as I can tell https://swift.org/blog/conditional-conformance/ says that Array now conforms to Hashable whenever its values conform to Hashable. As a workaround I have:

```
extension Array: Hashable where Element == Int {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        return debugDescription.hashValue
    }
}
```

But I’m still wondering why I don’t get Hashable for free.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automatic synthesis of `Hashable` for arrays of `Hashable` elements
is implemented in Swift 4.2. Automatic synthesis of `Equatable` for arrays of `Equatable` elements is implemented in Swift 4.1.

This seems to be misleading in the referenced blog entry, but is
listed clearly in the Swift [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> **Swift 4.2**
>
> The standard library types `Optional`, `Array`, `ArraySlice`,
>   `ContiguousArray`, `Dictionary`, `DictionaryLiteral`, `Range`, and `ClosedRange`
>   now conform to the `Hashable` protocol when their element or bound types
>   (as the case may be) conform to `Hashable`. This makes synthesized
>   `Hashable` implementations available for types that include stored
>   properties of these types.
>
> **Swift 4.1**
>
> The standard library types `Optional`, `Array`, `ArraySlice`,
>   `ContiguousArray`, and `Dictionary` now conform to the `Equatable` protocol
>   when their element types conform to `Equatable`. This allows the `==`
>   operator to compose (e.g., one can compare two values of type `[Int : [Int?]?]` with `==`), as well as use various algorithms defined for
>   Equatable element types, such as `index(of:)`.

This is also discussed in
[Let Optional, Dictionary and Array conditionally conform to Hashable](https://forums.swift.org/t/let-optional-dictionary-and-array-conditionally-conform-to-hashable/9046)
in the Swift forum:

> When synthesizing Hashable I noticed that Array, Optional and Dictionary do not conditionally conform to Hashable, while Set (unconditionally) does.

Note however that the ability to define conditional conformance
to a protocol *is* available in Swift 4.1, so you can generalize
your extension to

```
#if swift(>=4.2)
#else
extension Array: Hashable where Element: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        // ... whatever ...
    }
}
#endif
```